# Dynamic web scraping with goutte and Laravel

Tags: laravel, web, web-scraping

Is there a way to do a web scraping without define the HTML tags?

I have this code:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.cnnchile.com/opinion/');

$result = $crawler->filter('.inner-item__content > h2')->each(function ($node) {
   return $node->text();
});
```

but how you can see I always define the HTML tag where it's the content, is there a way to get in general the data? I mean without define that

Thanks

Comment: Web pages usually have more on them than just the info you are interested in.  How are you planning to identify the important bits to you?

Answer (score 0):

You want just the page content? Then use `body` as the filter tag.